# Inherit yml and add or update existing block

Tags: inheritance, yaml

I have yml

```
# test.yml
- name: test
  prop1: val1
  nested-prop:
     - val2
     - val3
```

Now I want to add another block and update existing `nested-prop` block so finale output might be like below.

```
# test.yml
- name: test
  prop1: val1
  nested-prop:
     - val2
     - val3
     - val4
  prop2: val5
```

It add `val4` in `nested-prop` block and add `prop2: val5` at the bottom.

This can we achive without any programming module like `pyyaml` or other. Using only yaml syntax?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Is there any way to achive this, using yaml syntax only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to to do this with just YAML. There is no way to merge items into a sequence like you want to do with `val4`.

Using aliases (`&foo`) and anchors (`*foo`) it *is* possible to merge one mapping into another:

```
my-alias: &my-alias
  prop2: val5

data:
  - name: test
    prop1: val1
    nested-prop:
      - val2
      - val3
    <<: *my-alias
```

This will produce a data structure equivalent to the following:

```
my-alias:
  prop2: val5

data:
  - name: test
    prop1: val1
    nested-prop:
      - val2
      - val3
    prop2: val5
```

Note that mappings in YAML are unordered, so the `prop2` key is not guaranteed to be "at the bottom" (since a mapping, being unordered, has no "bottom").

Comment: Thanks @Jordan, I will try to change my source file with `&` variables.